# Should DI container be global

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

As per my understanding, Dependency Injection container will register all classes during startup of application. How do I access the container when I go from one class library to another. Should container be static/global or container be passed to the called class in constructor.

Comment: You should not write code depending on the container **at all**. Only the startup code should use the container, all other places where you have dependencies you **only have the dependencies**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per my understanding, Dependency Injection container will register all classes during startup of application.

Correct

> How do I access the container when I go from one class library to another.

You don't. Only the start-up path of the application should have access to  the `Container`. Class libraries should *not* have a dependency on the DI Container, nor an abstraction that allows it to resolve any component. Spoken in DI terminology: to prevent using the DI Container as a [Service Locator](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/), you should refrain from using it outside the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

As an example, consider the following classes in your application:

```cs
public class OrderController { } // Presentation Layer
public class PlaceOrderHandler { } // Business Layer
public class SqlOrderRepository { } // Data Access Layer
```

In this example `OrderController` requires a `PlaceOrderHandler` to function, which in turn requires an `OrderRepository`.

Best practice is to apply [Constructor Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-constructor-injection/), which means that each class defines its required dependencies through its (sole) constructor. For instance:

```cs
public class OrderController
{
    public OrderController(IHandle<PlaceOrder> handler) { ... }

    public void PlaceOrder(PlaceOrderViewModel vm) { ... }
}

public class PlaceOrderHandler : IHandle<PlaceOrder>
{
    public PlaceOrderHandler(IOrderRepository repository) { ... }

    public void Handle(PlaceOrder command) { ... }
}

public class SqlOrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    public SqlOrderRepository(string connectionString) { ... }

    public Order GetById(Guid id) { ... }
    public void Save(Order order) { ... }
}
```

This allows your Composition Root to compose the following object graph:

```cs
new OrderController(
    new PlaceOrderHandler(
        new SqlOrderRepository(
            connectionString)));
```

This way, none of the classes require a dependency on a DI Container. In this code snippet, even, no DI Container is used.

In this last code snippet, I demonstrated the composition of object graphs using a concept called [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/), which basically means practicing DI without the use of a DI Container. Whether to use Pure DI or a DI Container is a topic of its own (which [Mark Seemann](https://blog.ploeh.dk) and I wrote extensively about in chapter 12 of [our book](https://mng.bz/BYNl)), but the main reason for me to show this example is because showing the construction of hand-wired object graphs helps demystifying the concept of DI.

But the main point here is that you should build up deep and *complete* object graphs of *all* components in the application inside your Composition Root. Whether you do this by hand (thus Pure DI as the previous example shows) or using a DI Container is up to you.